# Communication between booted Vagrant Virtual Machine and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, vagrant, chef-infra, virtual-machine, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create a VM to run few tests and destroy once done. I am using Jenkins 'Boot up Vagrant VM' option to boot up a VM and using chef to install required packages and run the tests in it. When testing is completed in this VM, is there any way it(VM) can communicate the results back to the job in Jenkins which triggered it?

I am stuck with this part.
I have implemented booting up of VM based on the custom vagrant box which has all essential packages and softwares required to run the tests.

Comment: Once the test is finished, you want to produce and publish a test report artifact . Then you would have to set up a jenkins trigger that would invoke a task to destroy the VM when the test report is available. Do you have a test report or do you publish it somewhere? How do you know the test is finished right now?

Comment: When the testing is done we generate JTL file which has the test results and we try to parse the same to know if there are any failures. We convert it into html pages for better readability.   Step to destroy VM once testing is done, is in place.

Comment: You may want to also save the test result before destroying the machine. You should copy the artifact to the "shared storage" as mounted into the vagrant box. By default the virtual machine folder  `/vagrant` is synced with Vagrantfile's parent directory. From jenkins, do a polling check let's say every second: if Vagrantfile's parent directory contains the test output report files then trigger the destroy task (after copying the result of course) :)

Comment: Ya I've known about the sync folders of Vagrant, and what you said does make sense(Didn't think that way). I just need to figure out how to do the polling to a specific directory.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin ???

Comment: Yep, that plugin looks to be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to Markus, who if had left an answer, I'd surely accept it.

I edited the Vagrantfile to add synched folders to 
`config.vm.synced_folder "host/","/guest"`.
It creates guest folder in the VM and the host folder which we created on the host system will also reflect on the VM.

All I did then as Markus suggested was do a polling from Jenkins (using Files Found trigger plugin) to some folder to search for some specific file that one is expected to see/communicated from VM.

In VM, whenever the testing is done, I'd simply put the result in host folder and it'd automatically reflect in my local machine, in the folder which Jenkins is polling and it will build the project whichever is polling this folder and ta dahhh ....!